# How to post message on FaceBook wall?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-wall

i want post a message on a facebook wall, i integrated facebook sdk in my project and i was coded like this, but there is no message display on facebook wall, but the information is coming from my Application...
this is the i am using for posting,

```
public void updateStatus(String accessToken, String message){  

       System.out.println("mes is "+message);           
       Bundle bundle = new Bundle();     
       bundle.putString("message", message);                    
       facebook.dialog(this, "stream.publish", bundle, this);

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. What I found from the search what is mentioned below in the Facebook [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed) of the **message** field of the `facebook.dialog()` method:

message: "This field will be ignored on July 12, 2011 The message to prefill the text field that the user will type in. To be compliant with Facebook Platform Policies, your application may only set this field if the user manually generated the content earlier in the workflow. Most applications should not set this."

You need to use the following instead:

```
Facebook.request("me/feed", bundle, "POST");
```

Comment: i changed what u told but i am not getting anything on the wall

Comment: what do you receive in logcat?

Comment: Can you share the permissions you used in `facebook.authorize`. Also, Do you have the Facebook App installed on the device/emulator. If yes, try removing it and test again.

Answer (score 0):

```
   public void showPostDailog ( String message ) {
        ProgressDialog authDialog = ProgressDialog.show ( SubmitComplaintActivity.this , "Please wait" ,
              "Posting Message"   , true , // indeterminate
                false ) ;

        Bundle parameters = new Bundle ( ) ;

        parameters.putString ( "link" , reult_complaint_url ) ;
        try {
            String response = mFacebook.request ( "me/feed" , parameters , "POST" ) ;
            System.out.println ( response ) ;
            isCompleteFacbook = true ;
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace ( ) ;
        }
        if ( authDialog != null && authDialog.isShowing ( ) ) {
            authDialog.dismiss ( ) ;
            authDialog.hide ( ) ;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Facebook SDK, then the code lies in the FacebookConnector.java class. postmessageinThread() function.

```
if ((fbconnector.getFacebook().isSessionValid())    {
    loginid=FacebookConnector.response;
    System.out.println("FB login ID is"+loginid);
    postMessageInThread(); //Replace this with another activity
    //String url="https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=TOKEN";
} else  {
SessionEvents.AuthListener listener = new SessionEvents.AuthListener() {
    public void onAuthSucceed() 
    {
       System.out.println("onAuthSucceed");
       postMessageInThread();
    }
    public void onAuthFail(String error) 
    {
    }
};
SessionEvents.addAuthListener(listener);            System.out.println("Login to Facebook");
        fbconnector.login();

    }
}
private String getFacebookMsg() {
    System.out.println("Login value from getFacenookMSg"+loginid);      
    return "test";
}
```